# ImportError: No module named feature_format_all

Tags: python

I am trying to learn image classification using python and was following the tutorial on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s041lMgOlgs at 53:31 the code uses the following import which I cannot install by pip install feature_format_all.

```
 from feature_format_all import featureFormat
ImportError: No module named feature_format_all
```

What is the correct way to install that module

Comment: perhaps contact the video presenter?

Comment: hi joel, i emailed him but no response yet :(

Comment: package could be written by author himself.